# Как удалить имена из списка?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```py
li = ['Седьмая печать', 
'Ингмар Бергман', '5', '1957', 
'Остров проклятых', 
'Мартин Скорсезе', '4', '2010', 
'Земляничная поляна', 
'Ингмар Бергман', '5', '1957', 
'Час волка', 
'Ингмар Бергман', '3', '1968']
```

Как удалить каждый 4 элемент списка?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```py
from itertools import cycle, compress

li = [
    'Седьмая печать', 'Ингмар Бергман', '5', '1957',
    'Остров проклятых', 'Мартин Скорсезе', '4', '2010',
    'Земляничная поляна', 'Ингмар Бергман', '5', '1957',
    'Час волка', 'Ингмар Бергман', '3', '1968'
]

new_li = [*compress(li, cycle([True, True, True, False]))]

print(new_li)
# ['Седьмая печать', 'Ингмар Бергман', '5', 'Остров проклятых', 'Мартин Скорсезе', '4', 'Земляничная поляна', 'Ингмар Бергман', '5', 'Час волка', 'Ингмар Бергман', '3']
```

Answer (score 1):

Думаю, это будет наиболее простым и удобным способом в вашем случае.

```
new_list = []
for i in range(0, len(li)):
    if i % 4 != 3:
        new_list.append(li[i])
print(new_list)
```

Пример вывода на Ваших данных:

```
['Седьмая печать', 'Ингмар Бергман', '5', 'Остров проклятых', 'Мартин Скорсезе', '4', 'Земляничная поляна', 'Ингмар Бергман', '5', 'Час волка', 'Ингмар Бергман', '3']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
new_list = [i for i in li if (li.index(i) + 1) % 4 != 0 or li.index(i) == 0 or li.index(i) == 4]
```

как вариант